# How to create isolate scope on element without directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

If I use ngRepeat in directive, it will create isolate scope. Look this example:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in model.items"></li>
</ul>
```

Imagine `model.items` array has 3 items.

This will create 3 scopes and bind them to 3 `li` elements. Each li element will have its own `item` object/value in its isolate scope. I can't acces this `item` values because `li` scopes are isolated.

How I can create same behaviour without creating custom directive and without `ngRepeat`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be slightly confused but let me try to clear things up...

First off, ngRepeat is a directive thus you can't really use it as an example for an isolate scope without a directive!
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Second of all, ngRepeat isn't creating an isolate scope. The reason you can't access `item` is because it creates a child scope for each iterated item. You *can't* (there are ways but let's just say can't for your own sanity) access data parent->child scopes and that's your issue there.

If you want to create an isolate scope manually, you can execute the following in your controller `$scope.$new(true)` but there are really specific reasons for this and its unlikely required for what you are trying to achieve.

Read up more about that here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$new

Take a look at this just to explore some scope isolation scenarios:
https://jsfiddle.net/r0m4n/6bjhcvq5/

Comment: My goal is to achieve "same" behaviour with scopes like in ngRepeat directive. I have 2 "blocks". This blocks are shown with ngRepeat now. I realised now, that 1 block should have 1 extra button. That means, that this blocks are not equal and cannot be shown with ngRepeat directive. I need two different blocks. Ofcourse, I can add some conditions inside html and hide extra block in 2nd block (its only needed for 1st), but it is noooot cool at all. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more specifics! As you said correctly, you could probably do an ng-if and include the button based upon a condition. That is likely your best bet as if you ever needed to iterate another item and include another button you could with ease. This approach has relatively low overhead and you wouldn't have to duplicate code. Why are you against it?!

Answer (score 0):

You can isolate the scope of an element by specifying an `ng-controller`:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">{{ HelloWorld }}</div>

app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.HelloWorld = "Hello, World!";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats the how you can create isolated scope with nested div's and ng-controller:

```
<div ng-controller="firstControllerScope">
    <h3>First controller</h3>
    <strong>First name:</strong> {{firstName}}<br />

    <div ng-controller="secondControllerScope">
      <h3>Second controller (inside First)</h3>
      <strong>First name (from First):</strong> {{firstName}}<br />
      <strong>Last name (new variable):</strong> {{lastName}}<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

in controller

```
var firstControllerScope = function ($scope)
{
  // Initialize the model variables
  $scope.firstName = "John";
};

var secondControllerScope = function ($scope)
{
  // Initialize the model variables
  $scope.lastName = "Doe";
};
```

working example is [here](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/basics/nestedcontrollers/)